# Network Programming Input Port Processing Speed

Tags: networking

So I'm using Computer Networking Top-Down approach and I do not get why:

If you have a 10Gbps input link and a 64-Byte IP datagram, why does the input port only have 51.2 ns to process the datagram before another datagram arrives?

Comment: Where does this number come from? Is this part of a spec? Or is this part of an arbitrary problem? This still seems like it is off topic for SO as it is not directly related to programming. May be better asked on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com), or one of the other [Stack Exchange Sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Answer (score 3):

Because 64B*8bpB/10Gbps = .0000000512s = 51ns, by cancellation of units.

Answer (score 0):

**GB is short for Gigabytes. Gb is short for Gigabits.**

8 bits = 1 byte

The tech industry measures data storage using GB (gigabytes). But it measures data speeds using Gb (gigabits).

So for example, you might buy a 500GB hard drive. That’s 500 Gigabytes of storage. But your broadband connection to your home might be 10Gbps, i.e, the transmission rate of the connection is 10 Gigabits per second.